# Htaccess redirect old links to new only if query parameter is present

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

The old directory structure is being replaced with a new one and the /oldLms directory needs to go. However, for backward compatibility we'd like to still keep those old links active, but redirect them to the new area using htaccess. I have the possibility the place a .htaccess at the root of the site.

Here's a sample "old" link:

http://url.com/oldLms/index.php?auth_regen=1&modname=login&op=confirm&login_user=Hanna&time=1406883178&token=3dd7d9b37b5cc962aa16e9df4acc470a

and a new one:

http://url.com/lms/index.php?r=site/sso&auth_regen=1&modname=login&op=confirm&login_user=Hanna&time=1406883178&token=3dd7d9b37b5cc962aa16e9df4acc470a

Basically the difference is that old ones are handled by

`/oldLms/index.php`

whereas the new ones are handled by

`/lms/index.php?r=site/sso`

All other query parameters need to be preserved during the redirect.

However, there is a catch! We only need to redirect links that have the `auth_regen=1` parameter. Others should not redirect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need following rule as **your first rule** in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)auth_regen=1(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^oldLms/(index\.php)$ /lms/$1?r=site/sso [L,NC,QSA,R=302]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add rewrite conditions:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/oldLms$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} auth_regen=1 # only if this occurs in the URI
RewriteRule /oldLms/.* /lms/$1
```